# Invalid Page Welcome Message for Messenger Destination Ads - Facebook

Tags: json, facebook

I am trying to create Facebook messenger ads, I get the following error for the past 3 weeks for certain Facebook pages and newly created Facebook pages, Its really frustrating

> Invalid Page Welcome Message for Messenger Destination Ads: The Message Text (page_welcome_message) is invalid for ads with Messenger as the destination.

But I don't get this error for old pages. I have enabled welcome message, instant reply and everything in facebook page message settings, still, I face this error.

Comment: 1200 views and still no solution , would be great if any facebook staffs or experts help this issue.

Comment: Without actual code I do not see how you can be assisted here.

Comment: 2k views , still no solution , there is no actual code involved , I am just trying to use default template.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem because I was sending an image before my first message. The first automated opt-in message you send must be just text.

Also, there's a 150 character limit for the first automated messages you send (including button names), so make sure your messages fit within that limit. Once the user interacts with your bot, you can send messages with photos and messages beyond the 150 character limit.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Once I deleted my image on the first message, this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

[You can find the solution at the following post. Follow the instructions](https://jocespot.wordpress.com/2018/05/22/manychat-facebook-ads-error-the-message-text-page_welcome_message-is-invalid-solution-part-2/)

I post the following summary:

> 1. Go to your Facebook ad – JSON code section
> 2. select everything and delete the code. This part is a bit
>      tricky because there’s at least a line or two of codes that Facebook
>      doesn’t delete automatically (not sure why)  so it may slip.
> 3. Make sure that you DO NOT leave a double `“Message”{ “Message”{}…..”` 
>      code.  This is where the error happens.  If you still see the double
>      `“Message….”` code select everything again and delete it.
> 4. You should see a black white screen.  You then copy and paste your
>      JSON code and save it.  The error should go away.

Comment: @Graciewilliams just delete the code as in the attached post and the error will go away `Invalid Page Welcome Message for Messenger Destination Ads: The Message Text (page_welcome_message) is invalid for ads with Messenger as destination.`. Somebody must have set up that message.

Answer (score 0):

For me in particular:

I use Manychat. The Manychat Growth tool that generated the JSON code to insert in the Facebook Ads Template had a button inside it. That ad with that JSON code produced this error.

When I changed the Growth tool to have no button, but a "quick reply" instead, and created a new Facebook template with that JSON code pasted inside it, there was no more Facebook Ads Error #1815471.

Answer (score -1):

Click on "Preview in Messenger" and wait for the message to be delivered to messenger. The error will go away after delivery.